# Boolean simplification of $AB'(B' + C)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplifying $AB'(B'+ C)$, then using the distributive property I know I would get

$AB'B' + AB'C$

I am just confused as to how to simplify $B'B'$

Answer (score 2):

$AB'B' + AB'C = AB' + AB'C = AB'(1 + C) = AB'1 = AB'$

$B'B'$ states "$B'$ and $B'$" which by idempotence is equivalent to $B'$.  And note that when $AB'$ is satisfied, then $AB'$ OR $ AB'C $ is satisfied, regardless of the truth value of $C$.

Comment: OH that makes sense! thank you for explaining for thoroughly.

Comment: @amWhy: great feedback, but no upvote or acceptance? Anyway +1!

Answer (score 0):

Use idempotence: $B'B'=B'.$ Then factor out the $AB'$ again and simplify.

Alternately, consider the [induced partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Definition) given by $a\le b$ iff $ab=a$ iff $a+b=b$. Under this partial order, $ab$ is the greatest lower bound of $a,b$ and $a+b$ is the least upper bound of $a,b.$ Then $AB'\le B'\le B'+C$, and so $AB'(B'+C)=AB'$.